# Calling a firebase function within a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, function, firebase, firebase-authentication

this is my javascript function with firebase inside:

```
function submitToDatabase(){
    var email = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error){
      console.log('i am erroring')
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
  })
};
```

this is where i am calling this function from my code:

```
username:<br>
          <input id="username" type="text" name="username" ><br>
          password:<br>
          <input id="password" type="text" name="password" ><br><br>
          <input type="submit" onclick=submitToDatabase() value="Submit">
```

I can verify that the function picks up the email and password values as i have console.logged them but it is jumping inside the error part of the function and i cannot work out why??
how can i call firebase.auth with inside my function

Comment: Just a quick thought, but have you checked what kind of error is given here? Does it contain a message?

Comment: Error code? and error message?

Comment: Are you using it on web? or NODEJS? . The implementation is quite different.

Comment: no error, only the console log and yes to nodejs

Comment: i was foolish, it is now working :)

Answer (score 0):

allow user to have a display name (vs showing their email to the world).  Try this:

```
  function registerPasswordUser(email,displayName,password,photoURL){
    var user = null;
    //NULLIFY EMPTY ARGUMENTS
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      arguments[i] = arguments[i] ? arguments[i] : null;
    }
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(function () {
      user = auth.currentUser;
      user.sendEmailVerification();
    })
    .then(function () {
      user.updateProfile({
        displayName: displayName,
        photoURL: photoURL
      });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      toast(error.message,7000);
    });
    toast('Validation link was sent to ' + email + '.', 7000);
    registerCard.style.display = "none";
  }
```